# Is Microsoft PowerApps integrated with Windows Workflow Foundation?

Tags: workflow-foundation-4, business-process-management, powerapps

I wonder if I could develop the business logic of a powerapp through Windows Workflow Foundation or some other bpm? Similar to Appian's Low Code and Appian's BPM, which are integrated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not directly - there are no connectors that would link PowerApps with WF. The main "workflow" engine in the PowerApps environment is [Microsoft Flow](https://flow.microsoft.com), for which there is a very tight integration.

Notice, however, that if your (existing) workflow can be exposed as a REST API (either directly, or via another custom API), then you should be able to consume it - take a look at the [Custom API tutorial](https://powerapps.microsoft.com/en-us/tutorials/register-custom-api/) for more information.

Comment: Cool! My workflow can be exposed as a rest api automaticaly with the tool I'm using to model it. Thanks!